# Who do you like most to invite vs Who would you most like to invite

Tags: idioms, comparative-constructions

Which of these two is correct or what is the difference between them. The first sounds awkward to me.

**1-Who do you like most to invite on your wedding?**
This would be answered: -"I most like to invite..."

**2-Who would you most like to invite to your wedding?**
This would be answered:-"I would most like to invite..."

Maybe "to your wedding" but "on your wedding day"?

[BTW these are from a student's English lesson in China, notorious for confusing distinctions.]

Questions like "What do you like least about your current job?" OR "Who do you like most, of all your teachers?" sound fairly normal. I am having trouble explaining what I do not like about the first sentence.

Comment: I think _prefere_ should be used instead of _like most_.

Comment: (ehm, typo, it's *_prefer_)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the *do you like* version is that despite the idiom *would like* (meaning roughly "want"), the word *like* does not otherwise mean *want*.

So although "I would like to invite […]" means roughly "I want to invite […]", "I like to invite […]" means roughly "I enjoy inviting […]". The latter does not really make sense in this context. (It could only make sense if inviting people to one's wedding is something that one does on a regular basis.)

Comment: Hey, Ruakh,I think you helped clarify something. In Chinese, there are two words for want: yao (a childlike "I want candy") and xiang (I would like).

Comment: So, "What would you like to do?" and "Where would you like to go?" are idioms that express the the xiang idea, polite inquiries.                           What threw me was "I would like to invite…", getting confused with other ideas associated with invitations;  wanting (someone to attend) and liking (them enough to ask). Thanks.